# How can I adjust the height of the breadcrumb preview window in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I enjoy being able to relatively efficiently navigate around the file system using the breadcrumb bar in VS Code. However, for larger directories, I find the window's maximum height not quite tall enough for my liking. Despite having a good look around the breadcrumb settings for an option to change its maximum height, I have come up a bit *short*.

Any guidance on how I could increase the max height of this handy little window would be greatly appreciated!

[image: The breadcrumb directory preview]

Comment: loosely historically related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/57437